# How do I get number of toll gates between two points in google direction api flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-directions-api, configmap

I want to get number of toll gates coming between two points i.e Source and the destination. I wanted to show the number of toll gates on google map that are coming on the way. How am I supposed to do this? I am using the distance formula that calculates the distance between those points. Can anyone help me with the code in flutter?

Comment: Directions API ( [Directions Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) and [Directions API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions) ) only feature avoiding tolls, and counting them is currently not implemented. If you want, you may consider making a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) to let this be supported by the Google Maps API.